# smartgwt offline-caching with no GWT module

Tags: smartgwt, offline-caching

I'm using  Eclipse 4.2, appengine-java-sdk-1.8.9, gwt-2.5.1, smartgwt-4.0p

I'm trying make the simple project like this - http://uptick.com.au/content/create-gwt-project 
but offline.

When I save page (as html page) it doesn't work offline and I receive alert - "GWT module may need to be (re)compiled".

My question is: how to change project to save it as html page (plus project_name_nocache.js file).

Thanks.

Comment: You do not need to save any page.

Comment: Follow the steps:  
1. set ANT_HOME and GWT_HOME  
2. open command window  
3. run command `webAppCreator -out myCRM au.org.myCRM.myCRM`  
4. run command `cd myCRM`  
5. run command `ant`  
6. run command `ant devmode`  
7. click Launch Default Browser

Comment: Try Google plugin for Eclipse to create a sample project. For more info [click](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started#creating).

Comment: Please let me know if still you have any issue.

Comment: Try SmartGWT getting started tutorial from [HERE](http://hilloldebnath.byethost3.com/2009/08/29/smartgwt-a-getting-started-guide/) to create a sample SmartGWT project.

Comment: In fact I want do next^

Comment: In fact I want to do next: 1). Make application. 2). Deploy it with Google App Engine. 3). Open it with any computer (no ANT or GWT) but with sertain browser. 4). Save application as html page (plus nocache.js). 5). Start saved page offline. 6). In future use com.smartgwt.client.util.Offline for storing data from application  with browser. Use application offline with stored data if have no internet access. Update browser storing data and Google Datastore data if have internet access. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting this error message because you might be trying to run/debug your application in **compiled mode**. In order to do so, you need to re-compile your application for GWT after every single change in code.

To avoid this, you should run/debug your application in **developer mode**.
See this [link](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html), to have idea on how to run GWT application in dev mode.